# In Thymeleaf, how to acquire HTML variable and send it to controller?

Tags: java, spring, html, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I have no idea how to retrieve image's name.

Required String parameter 'image.name' is not present. This is what I get after clicking on the button.

Controller's method

[image]

Page from that I'm trying to get image's name

[image]

What should I change to get this variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not provided name attribute in your output field, if you could set it to be like this it would know that you are referring to this field with name "image.name"

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="${image.name}" name="image.name">
```

Comment: I have tried this Sir but the result is still the same.
Thymeleaf does not see  image object's name and I don't know why

Comment: <output th:text="${image.name}" name="image.name"/>  gives me picture1.jpg, maybe my controller is wrong?

Comment: <output type="hidden" th:field="${image.name}" name="image.name" value="${image.name}"> tried this?

Comment: Yes and found that the  output tag should be swapped with input one. Now it looks like:  <input type="hidden" name="image.name" th:value="${image.name}"/>. Thank you for help Sir!